# How to show live data of Bitcoin in Blogspot by using XPath from Yahoo Finance?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code that I put in Blogspot:

```
<div>
  <h2>Bitcoin Price:</h2>
  <span id="bitcoin-price"></span>
</div>

<script>
  const url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-USD/";
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
      const parser = new DOMParser();
      const doc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html");
      const xpath = '//*[@id="quote-header-info"]/div[3]/div[1]/div/fin-streamer[1]';
      const element = doc.evaluate(xpath, doc, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
      const price = element.textContent;
      document.getElementById("bitcoin-price").textContent = price;
    });
</script>
```

The result I get:
[image]

I do expect that my Blog will shown live value of Bitcoin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really not recommended to access data in this way, websites that you don't own may change elements' location/attributes, what will break your XPath query and require to maintain it constantly.

You should always use API (when it's available). Since Yahoo have only backend API, you may use another platform, such as [RapidAPI](https://rapidapi.com/), to access the data from the frontend. I found you [this](https://medium.com/justinctollison/using-javascript-fetch-to-grab-yahoo-finance-api-949fd24876c9) article that explains how to do that.

For further explanation about why your way isn't working, you may read about [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), that blocks requests from outer websites to prevent unauthorized access.